# How to split a string with non-numbers as delimiter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I want to `split` a string in `C#`. It should `split` on the basis of a text in the string.Like i have a string `"41sugar1100"` , i want to `split` on the base of `text` in it that is `"sugar"`.How can i do this ?

NOTE: Without passing `"sugar"` directly as a `delimiter`.Because text can be change in next iteration.Means wherever it finds text in the string, it should split on the basis of that text.

Comment: you want to find the `sugar` in strings? only that specific word?

Comment: @Thomas any code for that please

Comment: What i'm missing: 1.More meaningful samples 2. A desired result 2. Your own try. For that reason it's also not so clear.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this right either? you want to get the numbers out of a string where any alpha-text is to be considered a delimiter?

Comment: @HugoYates yes you r right

Comment: @TimSchmelter expected result is 41,sugar,1100

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string input = "44sugar1100";
string pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+";            // Split on any group of letters

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
}
```

Comment: Dear it is returning empty string

Comment: short and sweet way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] array = "41sugar1100".ToCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Append letters and special char '#' when original char is a number to split later
foreach (char c in array)
    sb.Append(Char.IsNumber(c) ? c : '#');

// Split on special char '#' and remove empty string items
string[] items = sb.ToString().Split('#').Where(s => s != string.Empty).ToArray();

foreach (string item in items)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

// Output:  
// 41  
// 1100
```

Answer (score 0):

****Use char[] array for split a string from string****

```
 string s = "44sugar1100";
        char[] c = new char[] { 's', 'u', 'g', 'a', 'r' };
        string[] s1 = s.Split(c,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string s2 = s1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<firstNumber>\d+)(?<word>[^\d]+)+(?<secondNumber>\d+)", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

string s = "41sugar1100";
Match match = regex.Match(s);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            string firstNumber = match.Groups["firstNumber"].Value;
            string word = match.Groups["word"].Value;
            string secondNumber = match.Groups["secondNumber"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the string and put it into a char array
then int.tryparse each char in the array for example...

```
string myString = "44sugar1100";
int num=0; //for storage
string newString="";//for rebuilding
foreach(char ch in myString)
{
    if(int.TryParse(ch, out num)
    {
    newString+=num.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made my statement then wrote the code, then changed my mind on how to do it, I would follow the code

Answer (score -3):

```
string text = "41sugar1100";
string[] array = text.Split('sugar');
```

Comment: `Without passing "sugar" directly as a delimiter`

Comment: This does also not compile because `'sugar'` is not a `char`

Comment: You'd have to do `string[] array = text.Split(new string[]{"sugar"}, StringSplitOptions.None);` but then this still doesn't solve the original question :/